# Como remover do site uma palavra criada por um plugin

Tags: wordpress, localização, woocommerce

Utilizamos WordPress e WooCommerce no nosso site e para calcular o frete usamos o plugin [Postcode Shipping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postcode-shipping/).
Nosso frete tem 3 valores (grande São Paulo, interior de SP e cidades vizinhas) e é fixo cobrado apenas por pedido e não por produto.

A questão de conseguir ter 3 valores fixos para o frete em parte já esta resolvido. Porém quando um cliente informa um CEP que não há meio de frete disponível, ele aparece *Grátis*, como faço para remover a palavra "Grátis"? Já pesquisei no arquivo do plugin mas não consegui.

[image: snapshot do total no carrinho]

Comment: Olá, Cortez, editei sua pergunta para reduzir bastante sua descrição do frete já que o problema que vc pergunta não é esse, é como remover uma palavra. Mudei o título também para deixá-lo mais genérico e útil para quem tiver um problema semelhante.

Answer (score 1):

É, o plugin [não tem](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/postcode-shipping/trunk/) arquivos de tradução (`nome-pt_BR.po` ou `.mo`). Procurei também dentro do WooCommerce e não está. Isso significa que provavelmente está no seu tema <sup>(ou num outro plugin)</sup>.

A via mais direta é editar os [arquivos de linguagem](http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Instalando_WordPress_em_seu_Idioma). Para editar arquivos `.po` use o [PoEdit](http://poedit.net/) (e fazer upload do arquivo `.mo` criado) ou o [Codestyling Localization](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/) (e editar direto no site).

Outra possibilidade é usar jQuery:

```
add_filter( 'wp_head', function()
{
    if( !is_page( 'PÁGINA-DO-CARRINHO' ) ) // http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) 
    { 
        $('#BOX-CORRESPONDENTE').text( 'Seu texto sem grátis' );
    });
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

Ou então, se nada disso adiantar, fica a opção barra pesada que é procurar dentro de todas as traduções para modificar a *string*. Para isso, use o plugin [*Retranslate*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3675/12615) modificando o **`context`** para *`frontend`*.

Answer (score 1):

Conteúdo original:

> Meu conteúdo. (Grátis)

Código HTML original:

```
<div>Meu conteúdo. (Grátis)</div>
```

Javascript a inserir:

```
<body onload="document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('(Grátis)', '');">
```

Resultado final:

> Meu conteúdo.

Brutal, mas dependendo do seu caso eficaz.

[Exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4aws4tv7/)

Answer (score 0):

Já deu uma boa olhada na configuração do plugin? É um erro bem bobo pra acontecer, tente ver direto com suporte do plugin